# what engine oil does a 1992 subaru liberty auto stationwagon need? Answers in "W" units please

Tags: engine, oil, subaru

What engine oil does a 1992 Subaru Liberty auto station wagon need? Answers in "W" units please.

I need to add oil and I cannot find a good reference as to what to use - the oil at the garages are 20w/50 w etc and I have no idea what to use.

Comment: Have you checked the owner's manual?

Comment: Also, what you call "W units", like 10W40, is the "SAE specification" and actually measures the oil's viscosity at low and high temperatures.  See http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/12701/1419 for much more detail.

Comment: It usually says right on the filler cap. Have you checked there?

Comment: It will depend on the engine size and running. Subarus typically use 10W40, 5W40 or 10W30 but your manual will tell you which you need.

Answer (score 1):

4.5 liters of semi-synthetic 10w40.

Comment: Please provide a reference. Also, which engine was this for?