# Can I use Turbo Diesel oil in my Petrol car?

Tags: oil

I need to top up the oil in my 2003 Opel Agila with some 5W-40 oil. However, the only oil that I have are:

- [Mobil 1 Turbo Diesel 5w-40](http://www.mobil.com/USA-English/Lubes/PDS/GLXXENPVLMOMobil1_Turbo_Diesel_Truck_5W-40.aspx)
- [Halfords **Ford** Oil 5w-40](http://www.halfords.com/motoring/engine-oils-fluids/engine-oil/halfords-5w30-part-synthetic-ford-oil-2l)

However, I have a Vauxhall/Opel Agila 1.2 Petrol (naturally aspirated).

Can I use these oils? Will I damage my engine by doing so?

Should I be using Vauxhall oil ([example](http://www.halfords.com/motoring/engine-oils-fluids/engine-oil/halfords-vauxhall-opel-gm-5w30-fully-synthetic-oil-2l)) instead of just generic 5W-40?

**EDIT: The manual says this:**

> Engine Oil Grade: ACEA A3/B3
>
> Engine Oil Viscosity: 0W-X, 5W-X, 10W-X (where X is greater than or equal to 30)

Comment: Which standards does the oil need to meet for your car?

Comment: @HandyHowie, Updated question

Comment: I don't think they meet the cars requirements.

Comment: Oil is always a highly controversial topic among gear heads. I would read this and form your own opinion. http://www.machinerylubrication.com/Read/28576/comparing-gasoline-diesel-engine-oils- . Personally, I would use Diesel oil only in a pinch or temporarily to help clean up a dirty engine (it generally has more detergents).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as the oil meets the specifications for the oil your car needs, then yes, you can use them. If you don't understand about oil specification, [look at this answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/12701/4152) I posted a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

Even though your oils complete the viscosity criteria, i don't advise pouring in diesel engine oil in a petrol engine . The two oils are formulated a bit differently each suiting the need of the engine . A small experiment was carried out , in which petrol engine oil was poured in a diesel swift . From the results it was very clear the oil was not at all suitable for the engine , chances are the same problem will be faced in the opposite condition.
Many car companies provide engine oil under their own branding, but they are manufactured by third parties. 
(The oil used in the experiment was branded by suzuki but manufactured by castrol) 
There is no problem in using generic oil as long the quality is good.

Comment: What experiment are you citing?  What results are you citing?

Comment: A experiment was performed by suzuki in which the engine oils of a diesel and petrol swift were interchanged. Results indicated that the diesel engine started running a bit too hot. Due to poor wether the second part of the experiment was not performed. And if later it was performed, i was not there to observe .

Comment: @Akra Patra - Is this experiment published anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that one can cross additive packages even for as long as an oil change, with little or no measurable difference.

The diesel oil handles particulates better and the gasser oil has buffers for some combustion by products, but both will lubricate. Years ago oils were frequently rated for both diesel and gas, but the requirements started diverging. In a pinch you could use the diesel oil in the gasser car.

But practically, if you are looking at changing the oil, why not get the right stuff.  Carry a quart of the diesel oil in the trunk as an emergency quart if you are ever in a bind. At least that way, the mix is dilute, and more temporary than for a full change.