# Lexus ES 350 2009 recommended Motor oil viscosity

Tags: oil-change, lexus

[image]I just bought a Lexus ES350 2009 and I am so confused about the oil I should be using, in the owner manual they recommend SL or SM 20W50 oil for temperatures between -7 and 38 and online search shows 5W30, I live in Jordan where temperature is between -2 and 40 degrees, and rarely reaches those extremes.

What is the oil I should be using?

The car has 81K miles.

Comment: Three answers saying use 5W-30 oil, and all you have just done is edit the question. Why not select an answer?

Comment: Are those answers considering that the car was manufactured for the middle east? that is my only concern.

Answer (score 0):

20w50 is too thick.

Considering the mileage I would stick with 5w30.

Comment: Why would the manual say 20W50 for temperature between -7 to 38? which is almost exactly the same as Jordan weather

Answer (score 0):

SN+ is the most current oil specification. Use 5W-30.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you got your information from. Here's [the page from the 2009 350 ES](https://www.manualowl.com/am/Lexus/2009-ES%20350/Manual/6547) Owners Manual:

[image]

It clearly states to use 5W-30. 20w-50 isn't mentioned.

Comment: The car is made for the middle east, gulf area where the weather gets extremely hot 40+ for like 6 months of the year, it has been imported to Jordan where the weather is way much moderate -2 to 40 and not that often reaches those, attaching a picture of the owner manual.

Comment: @QuakeCore - Look at the bottom of the page which you provided. The answer is right there where it says: "**Recommended Viscosity**" ... says exactly what I just showed you, which is to run 5W-30 oil. Should work flawlessly in the lower temperatures you see there in Jordan. I see where it says what you are talking about (the 20W-50), however, as stated, the 5W-30 will run you just fine. And work even better if you run synthetic. [Look at this chart](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/12701/4152) for more information as to oil viscosity and heat.