# A3/A5 ACEA Oil Question

Tags: oil

I’m getting confused about what this actually means. My cars manual specifies A3/A5 oil. I can’t find anything labelled A3/A5.

Does A3/A5 mean ‘A3 or A5’? Or is A3/A5 a specific grade itself?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! The "A3/A5" *appears* to be an ACEA rating, but it doesn't exist as a rating [in their 2023 publication](https://www.acea.auto/files/2023_ACEA_oil_sequences_light-duty_engines.pdf). [This post may be of help, too.](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/12701/4152)